# I do not understand how the temp is keeping head1 and head2 at same time

Tags: linked-list

```
Node* mergelist(Node* head1, 
                Node* head2)
{
    // Base cases
    if (!head1)
        return head2;
    if (!head2)
        return head1;
  
    Node* temp = NULL;
    if (head1->data < head2->data) 
    {
        temp = head1;
        head1->next = mergelist(head1->next, 
                                head2);
    }
    else 
    {
        temp = head2;
        head2->next = mergelist(head1, 
                                head2->next);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it has two values at the same time? What gave you this idea?

Answer (score 0):

`temp` is not keeping `head1` and `head2` at same time.

It is *either* `head1` *or* `head2`.

`temp` represents what will be the head of the merged list. There are only two candidates for this: either the merged list will start with the first node of the *first* list or the first node of the *second* list, whichever has the least value. This is what `if` condition is checking, and so either we get into the `if` block or in the `else` block (not both).

Once we know which node will be the head of the merged list (either `head1` or `head2`) we should exclude that node from further merge logic, and continue with the merge *without* that node. This is done here by calling the function recursively (without that node).

A better name for `temp` would be `headOfMergedList`.